# Is there a way to store multiple records rather than using multiple rows in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, dataset

I would like to make full use out of MySQL for the purpose of a (web) application I have developed for a chiropractor.

So far I have been storing in a single row for [every year] for what are called progress notes. The table structure looks something like this (progress_note_id, patient_id, date (Y-0-0), progress_note). When the client wishes to append for the year of the current progress notes, he simply clicks at the top of a textarea (html), which I use TinyMCE JavaScript library, to make a new entry date along with the shorthand notes to go at the beginning of the column (progress_note). So far its been working ok, if there are 900+ clients (est.) there could potentially be 1300+ progress notes, for each year since the beginning of the application (2018).

Now the client wishes to be able to see previous progress notes (history), but is unable to modify any previous notes, while still be able to write new ones. The solution I have come up with is to use XML inside the textarea, and use PHP to decipher the new notes from the old ones.

My problem however is if I should have to convert my entire table from a yearly to a daily, that it could take up a lot of time and energy to convert multiple notes into each single rows, (est. 10x) Which could end up being 13,000+ rows. I realize that no matter what method I choose to do is going to be a lot of work. Another way around this perhaps I found was to use XML column type in MySQL to potentially store multiple records, and if I wish to append it, all I would need is PHP to interpret the entire XML and add a new child node, to the beginning. Each progress note is 255 - 500 chars. And in worst case scenario, if the patient was to be 52 times a year (1 for every week), there shouldn't be a large enough overhead.

Is this the correct way to solving this problem? I do wish to keep with MySQL DB and I realize that MySQL is not an intended for XML. And for some clarification, what I hope to accomplish is the same thing I intended to do with current progress notes, but with XML. I believe in ascending order (newer -> oldest).

```
<xml_result>
  <progress_note>
    <date>2020-08-16</date>
    <content></content>
  </progress_note>
<xml_result>
```

Thank-you for any of your time and for any suggestions.

Comment: The benefit of using XML, is that I can create a temp. MySQL table and populate it with the content from the XML datasets. Thus I can search for the last 3-5 notes, fill up the textarea and separate the new notes from the old notes using XML.

Comment: 13000 is a tiny number of rows.  don't be afraid of it.

Comment: I support databases with _billions_ of rows in a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, 13000+ is not a problem for mysql. In most case for web application, mysql can handle more than 10m+ records for a single instance with a good performance.

Secondly, you can use either XML or JSON format in a text field and handle the decoding in your application.